# My magento 2 website's menu is not displaying, it is loading in esi.include tag

Tags: magento-2.0

Please see the console highlighted tag below :

https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-bbh1XSOt524/Wfcce1p3G3I/AAAAAAAAAv0/rRGBZ28R8403rTGKUc6U-wQCfeQzHZe7wCL0BGAYYCw/h800/2017-10-30.png

Comment: Maybe this can help you https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5423

Answer (score 1):

Edge Side Includes (ESI) is a technology to address this. An edge side include is where a web server returns an HTML page that can be cached, but where parts of the page are replaced with an “include” reference (URL) it will return just the content for that part of page (such as customer’s name). Using ESI, load is reduced on web server – most of the heavy work is cached, with HTTP requests for small parts of a page where the content needs to be different per user.

Note: ESI is used for caching. So clear all the cache and then deploy the code.

Please follow the url : https://alankent.me/2014/12/09/magento-2-caching-overview/

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all.

Answer (score -2):

Wwitch off the varnish and just use the  default magento caching it went back to normal. Then you can see the top menu.